# nullreferenceexception when accessing ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

**Controller**

```
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Dashboard/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["PartnerID"] = GetPartnerID();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult OutboundTransfers()
        {
            var partnerId = ViewData["PartnerID"].ToString();//NULL EXCEPTION
            InventoryEntities context = new InventoryEntities();
            var result = context.GetOutboundTransfers(partnerId);
            //var result = context.GetOutboundTransfers("3000017155");

            return View(result);
        }

        private static string GetPartnerID()
        {
            return "3000017155";
        }

    }
}
```

**View (Dashboard/Index)**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <%= Html.Action("OutboundTransfers")%>
</asp:Content>
```

I am a beginner to MVC 2.  I read the ViewData should be accessible to the partial view (OutboundTranfers.ascx) as a copy.  So, why do I get a null reference here?

Comment: @Kirk: this looks pretty much like an answer

Comment: @Henk, yeah, guess you're right.  Moved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `ViewData["PartnerID"]` in Index(), try creating a constructor for your controller and setting the value there like so:

```
public DashboardController()
{
    ViewData["PartnerID"] = GetPartnerID();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewData` is presumably not null -- `ViewData["PartnerID"]` is null. (the item is not in the `ViewData`) Also, you set the `PartnerID` data in one action, and fetch it in the other. `ViewData` is not preserved across requests/actions.

(Moved out of comments into an answer...)

Comment: This does tell me why the error occurs.  Perhaps with my skill level I lack the foresight, but this doesn't help me fix the problem of maintaining state.